# How to set unbuffered IO in `screen`?

Tags: gnu-screen

[I use `screen` as a `minicom` replacement](http://blog.schraner.cc/2011/02/linux-use-screen-to-connect-cisco-devies-with-console-port), but the only problem is I don't get all output immediately, because of buffering. Is there a way to turn off buffering for `screen`?

Comment: What do you expect at 9600 baud?

Comment: @jordanm Actually I set it to 115200, unlike the blog post.

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting the output lines (OL) of termcap to 0 within your screenrc file. This may get you what you want:

```
termcapinfo xterm* OL=0
```

There may be some other options worth checking out in this [`screen` doc](http://www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/RZ/software/screen/screen_16.html).